# plot an additional independent column with ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

With data on Cohorts, Periods, and births, death, and marriage counts I plot deaths and marriages for each point of cohort and period. The births do remain the same for every period though which is why I do not want to write them where the other number are written but in front of the plot. In other words, I have a data frame:

```
Lexisres <- structure(list(Cohort = c(1760L, 1760L, 1760L, 1760L, 1760L, 
    1760L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1780L, 1780L, 
    1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 
    1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 
    1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 
    1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 1820L, 1820L, 1820L, 1820L, 
    1820L, 1820L, 1820L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 
    1840L, 1840L, 1840L, 1840L, 1840L, 1850L, 1850L, 1850L, 1850L, 
    1860L, 1860L, 1860L, 1870L, 1870L, 1870L, 1880L), Births = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 
    69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 
    331L, 331L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 
    508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 469L, 469L, 469L, 
    469L, 469L, 469L, 469L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 595L, 
    595L, 595L, 595L, 595L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 
    361L, 361L, 361L, 1L), Period = c(1810L, 1820L, 1830L, 1840L, 
    1850L, 1860L, 1810L, 1820L, 1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1810L, 
    1820L, 1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1810L, 1820L, 
    1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1810L, 1820L, 
    1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1820L, 1830L, 
    1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 
    1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 
    1890L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 
    1890L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1880L, 1890L, 1890L, 1890L), Marriages = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 34L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 67L, 236L, 24L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 160L, 
    272L, 35L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 207L, 251L, 45L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 137L, 296L, 34L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 184L, 330L, 35L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 255L, 289L, 49L, 0L, 0L, 174L, 429L, 53L, 0L, 232L, 538L, 
    0L, 0L, 361L, 1L), Deaths = c(5L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 5L, 3L, 13L, 
    25L, 24L, 44L, 33L, 6L, 13L, 21L, 28L, 39L, 40L, 44L, 9L, 1L, 
    22L, 37L, 71L, 65L, 61L, 112L, 96L, 30L, 1L, 1L, 45L, 95L, 69L, 
    81L, 117L, 130L, 121L, 25L, 5L, 63L, 73L, 80L, 82L, 114L, 144L, 
    106L, 5L, 67L, 46L, 69L, 91L, 108L, 143L, 2L, 48L, 67L, 80L, 
    89L, 120L, 2L, 54L, 83L, 79L, 82L, 5L, 56L, 62L, 99L, 3L, 43L, 
    72L, 1L, 35L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Cohort", "Births", "Period", 
    "Marriages", "Deaths"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -75L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
        Cohort = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector")), Births = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector")), Period = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector")), Marriages = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector")), Deaths = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector"))), .Names = c("Cohort", "Births", "Period", 
    "Marriages", "Deaths")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

and I plot marriages and deaths like this:

```
ggplot(data = Lexisres) + 
  geom_blank(aes(x = Period, y = Cohort)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = Period, y = Cohort, 
                label = paste("\nDeaths: ", Deaths, "\nMarriages: ", Marriages)), 
            size = 3.25, check_overlap = TRUE) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1900, 10)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1880, 10)) +
  theme_bw()
```

My idea was just to add an independent column that displays the births to the left for each Cohort respectively. So I was able to do that for the births, however, not the rest is quite destroyed.

```
ggplot(data = Lexisres) + 
  geom_blank(aes(x = Period, y = Cohort)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = Period, y = Cohort, 
                label = paste("\nDeaths: ", Deaths, "\nMarriages: ", Marriages)), 
            size = 3.25, check_overlap = TRUE) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1900, 10)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1880, 10)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = Cohort, label = paste("\nBirths: ", Births)))
```

[image]

What could I do here?

Comment: Try changing `x = 0` in your 2nd attempt to something closer to your plot's x-axis range, e.g. `x = 1790`? & set `check_overlap = TRUE` as before.

Comment: that works! thank you!